# Will request.getRequestDispatcher().forward creates new thread?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a use case that the request to be dispatched by trimming request URL to same context by setting some attributes with it. Will this be handled in same thread or in new thread?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will be handled in the same thread. The [Servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) states

> The Container Provider should ensure that the dispatch of the request
>   to a target  servlet occurs in the same thread of the same JVM as the
>   original request.

It does seem like this is a recommendation, but most implementations I know of do it in the same thread.